# C# SoundPlayer Question

Tags: c#

I'm trying to get one .wav file to play as ambient music though when another sound is played, it halts the ambient music and I've tried doing play-loop and tried the various sync, async , load.

I think I'm missing something here. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429513/play-wav-file-async-multiple-times-with-net) on SO and the suggestions made there. The basic problem is that `SoundPlayer` can only play one sound stream at a time - if you want to play multiple sounds concurrently you need a different solution.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use Windows Media Player for the ambient sound, and play another sound with SoundPlayer at the same time:

```
// example begin
WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.URL = "<theAudioFile>";
mediaPlayer.settings.setMode("loop", true);
mediaPlayer.controls.play();
// example end
```

A reference to Windows **Media Player assembly** needs to be added to the solution as well.