# Playing 2 sounds together at same time

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

Designing a game for any laptop:

I want to play 2 sounds at the same time! A background music and a sound when pressing on a button!

Using `System.Media` won't allow me to play 2 sounds together. For background music, I used the following:

```
SoundPlayer sp = new SoundPlayer(@"..\..\bin\debug\tribal dance.wav");
sp.Play;
```

If I played another `SoundPlayer`, the previous one stops!

I want the background music to keep playing until the form is closed! And at the same time, if a button is clicked, another sound will be played with the music!

I also tried added the Windows Media Player to the toolbox and used it (allowing me 2 play 2 sounds at same time). That works fine but the path will give an error if I put it `(@""..\..\bin\debug\tribal dance.wav");`
and I need to put it that way in order to be read by any computer.

Any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Play wav file async multiple times with .net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429513/play-wav-file-async-multiple-times-with-net)

Comment: This is not a direct answer to your question, but I highly recommend using FMOD for sound in your game. It is very easy to use and designed for games.

Answer (score 8):

You CANNOT play two sounds at once using SoundPlayer.

SoundPlayer is using the native WINAPI [PlaySound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd757715(v=VS.85).aspx) function to accomplish the task which has no support for playing simultaneous sounds.  Creating multiple instances of SoundPlayer won't help.

There are many options most of which involve implementing a lot of the low level API to window's native audio [library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd757715(v=VS.85).aspx) or [DirectSound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb318665(VS.85).aspx) (note neither are C# and require alot of interop code)

The simplest option would be to depend on windows media player to play the audio for you.

Add a reference to "C:\Windows\System32\wmp.dll"

then use

```
var player = new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer();
player.URL = @"..\..\bin\debug\tribal dance.wav";
```

Note: play starts immediately after setting the URL property

The down side of this approach is your reliance on media player for your application to work properly.  On the upside, you can use any file format media player supports.

Answer (score 0):

Using (WMPLib) Windows Media Player Library you can do this easily. Keep Your file in Debug/Sound folder and follow the following code. This will run 2 file simultaneously. To Add WMPLib  in your project add it by NuGet Package Manager.

```
 WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer wplayer = new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer();
 WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer wplayer2 = new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer();     
 string play_string = "be.mp3";
 wplayer.URL = @"SOUND/" + play_string;
 wplayer.controls.play();
 string play_string2 = "ba.mp3";
 wplayer2.URL = @"SOUND/" + play_string2;
 wplayer2.controls.play();
```

Answer (score -4):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd562851%28v=VS.85%29.aspx this article may help
If you need absolute path to file you can use next code

```
string soundFile = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "file.wav");
```