# C# playing multiple audio files at once from your resources?

Tags: c#, resources, wav, audio

I'd like to be able to press a button to play a sound of a button being pressed while music is already playing. SoundPlayer is no help because it stops the music to play the sound.
I have added the sounds to my Resources (WindowsFormsApplication2.Resources.Properties.button) and I don't want to have to type in the file location.

Answer (score 1):

Answer from [MerickOWA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4740262/playing-2-sounds-together-at-same-time)

> You CANNOT play two sounds at once using SoundPlayer.
>
> SoundPlayer is using the native WINAPI PlaySound function to accomplish the task which has no support for playing simultaneous sounds. Creating multiple instances of SoundPlayer won't help.
>
> There are many options most of which involve implementing a lot of the low level API to window's native audio library or DirectSound (note neither are C# and require alot of interop code)
>
> The simplest option would be to depend on windows media player to play the audio for you.
>
> Add a reference to "C:\Windows\System32\wmp.dll"
>
> then use
>
> ```
> var player = new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer();
> player.URL = @"..\..\bin\debug\tribal dance.wav";
> ```
>
> Note: play starts immediately after setting the URL property
>
> The down side of this approach is your reliance on media player for your application to work properly. On the upside, you can use any file format media player supports.